# Why was Earl's footsteps shown multiple times?

Tags: analysis, the-mule

In *The Mule*, there were multiple instances where the camera specifically focused on Earl's footsteps, especially at the end (when Earl finally gets caught by DEA on the highway, and then, when he's walking out of court).

What's the significance/purpose of zooming in on his footsteps?